# Disable one item in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Need to remove from one item in `ExpandableListView` image of arrow and possibility to expand this item.
I override:

```
@Override
public int getGroupType(int groupPosition) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if(headerTitle.equals("History")) {
        return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
    }
    return TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

In `getGroupView` i  switch `getGroupType(groupPosition)` and choose layouts.
Now my item have layout that i need, but its still xpandable. 
How to fix it? 
Something like: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                              int groupPosition, long id) { 
if(groupPosition==1)
   return true; // This way the expander cannot be collapsed
else
   return parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
      }
});
```

Comment: Now my items dont roll up and arrow is still at item :(

Comment: change "return parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition);" on "return false;"